# ubuntu:ubuntu owns "/" - all server files

Tags: server, permissions, sudo, users, chown

So recently, I made a mistake. I did;

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /
```

Now, my server is pretty non-functioning, and the fact that my server is using 100% of it's space, doesn't make the situation any better.

( I still have access to the headless terminal, but cant `su` )

I really need help with how I can revert this change.

So the outcome I am looking for: Reverting all permissions in root, to the default, and functioning Ubuntu.

**Ubuntu 22.04**

Comment: This is a fatal mistake because it changes the ownership of every file on your system. The system relies on correct ownership and permissions to run. You'll need to reinstall the system. Don't reuse files from this installation because files will have incorrect ownership and permission values. Restore files from backups taken before you used this command.

Comment: "So the outcome I am looking for: Reverting all permissions in root, to the default, and functioning Ubuntu." start a live session and manually alter all the files you changed to ubuntu:ubuntu.  But I do agree with Nmath... a reinstall without format will take a lot less time.

Comment: ... see also [Linux Ubuntu Server - sudo chown -R user:user /](https://askubuntu.com/questions/912555/linux-ubuntu-server-sudo-chown-r-useruser)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What if I accidentally run command "chmod -R" on system directories (/, /etc, ...)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc)